# How can I import a Custom Theme into a Google Sheets?

Tags: google-sheets

I have created a custom theme in Google sheets for my company to use and keep colors consistent in all charts they create with Google sheets. I am able to create the custom theme in a Google sheet I made, however, when I create a new Google Sheet and try to import or apply the theme, it is nowhere to be found. The only way I am able to use it is by making a copy of the Sheet containing the theme and creating the new chart right in the copy of that file.

Does anyone know of any other way to apply a custom theme to a Google Sheet which is more intuitive? Is there an 'import theme' option I am overlooking?

Thanks, efrozit

Answer (score 1):

The best way to do this will be to use GSuite. You must be an admin with Drive and Docs privilege to do this.

1. Sign in to your [Google Admin console](https://admin.google.com/) using an administrator account.
2. From the Admin console Home page, go to **Apps > G Suite > Settings for Drive and Docs > Templates**. To see Apps, you might have to click More controls at the bottom.
3. Choose whether to **enable custom templates for your organization**. If you uncheck this box, users can’t submit or use custom templates, but they can still use the standard template gallery.

If you do not have admin access, just allow someone with admin access duplicate your custom template and guide them to do the above.

Comment: I have this enabled, but I'm still not seeing a place to actually add a new theme in google sheets?